# Using namespace as type error

Tags: c#, namespaces, drawing

I am currently translating my java game engine into c#. Every thing is fine until I started writing the package `com.gej.graphics`. In c#, I wrote it like this.

```
namespace GECS.Graphics {}
```

But compiler says this error.

```
'GECS.Graphics' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type' (CS0118)
   - C:\Users\sr....ECS\Core\Game.cs:33,36
```

This is the text containing at the line

```
public virtual void Render(Graphics g) {}
```

The actual `Graphics` class is from `System.Drawing`.

My requirement is that this class is to be extended by users and hence they should have no conflicts with it.

Thanks

Comment: So, try saying `System.Drawing.Graphics g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your class with the Namespace as:

```
public virtual void Render(System.Drawing.Graphics g) { }
```

Since there is a conflict in names of your namespace and `Graphics` class, you may consider naming your namespace different, or you can always use the [fully quilified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) name.

Comment: Thanks. Decided to change the name of namespace to `GraphicsUtil`

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati, you are welcome, and that is probably a better solution then using the fully qualified name

Answer (score 1):

```
public virtual void Render(System.Drawing.Graphics g) {}
```

You need to specify the namespace due to you also creating a custom namespace with the name name as `Graphics`.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid to create namespace which can conflict with standart namespaces.
I your case you should use `System.Drawing.Graphics` name entirely, to avoid conflicts with `GECS.Graphics`.

Another solution could be [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) directive to create an alias for a namespace or a type.

For example:

```
using DrawingGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics;
```

after:

```
public virtual void Render(DrawingGraphics  g) 
{
}
```